# passing values to pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I am very confused by using pointers. In the code below, if I set currentYear = 2010, I expect the value of 2010 to be assigned to initYear. But when I debug it, in the first line of the code, inityear = 2009. In the last line of the code, initYear also equals 2009, and currentYear = 2010.

Anyone can explain why this happens, and how I can make initYear to be 2010 when currentYear is 2010? Thanks.

Here is the code:

```
 int initYear = pEnvContext->currentYear;
      for ( int i=0; i < m_numberOfRuns; i++ )
         {  
         UpdateMonteCarloInput(pEnvContext,i);
         pEnvContext->run=i; 
         pEnvContext->currentYear=initYear;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a reference:

```
int& initYear = pEnvContext->currentYear;
```

Now `initYear` is basically another way to access the value of `currentYear`. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29) to learn more about references.

Comment: Thanks. So, pEnvContext actually points to the address of currentYear, which is an address, not a value. Am I correct? Sorry for the stupid question, but I am new to C++, and is very confused.

Comment: `pEnvContext` points to some class and `currentYear` is a member variable of this class which you can access by writing `pEnvContext->currentYear`.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
int initYear = pEnvContext->currentYear;
```

copies the value stored in pEnvContext->currentYear to the initYear variable; so, no matter what will happen with currentYear, initYear contains its own copy.

If you want to have a reference to the currentYear and you want it to be updated when the currentYear is updated, use a reference (as Danvil stated before).

Comment: Thanks, Danvil and Oopscene.